# Grunt hostname 0.0.0.0 access is denied

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm wanting to view my SPA on a few different devices on my network, so in my Grunt file I changed the `hostname` to '0.0.0.0' as Grunt instructs, my connect task/object now looks like this:

```
// The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: '0.0.0.0',
        livereload: 35729
      },
```

Now when I run `grunt serve` the app opens the browser at `http://0.0.0.0:9000/` however my application isn't shown, I am given the following Error:

```
ERROR

The requested URL could not be retrieved

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: "http://0.0.0.0:9000/"

Access Denied.

Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what I should do to fix this issue. I have tried using `hostname: '*'` but that doesn't do anything but how the same error.

I am developing on OS X 10.9.2

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the link to the documentation which states this?

Answer (score 2):

Setting hostname to '0.0.0.0' is correct. You can connect to your server by connecting to `http://localhost:9000`. Alternatively, you can use the output of `hostname` to connect with the machine. Optionally, you should also set the baseUrl variable in your tests to connect to

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It seems that the '0.0.0.0' setting allows you to call your site from outside your computer; but screws the call to the web browser asking it to load a page located in an invalid server "http: / / 0.0.0.0"

If you replace the address to the right server name instead of 0.0.0.0 it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your own ip address instead of the `0.0.0.0`.
With this grunt launch the server on your ip. You can use your mobile to.
The livereload will work on your desktop and on your mobile.

It's not the best way if your work by team because each one have his ip address but it's good enough if you work alone.